# Доступ к базе данных MySQL через CDN cloudflare

Tags: mysql, сеть, cloudflare, cdn

Есть сервер с установленным MySQL (предположим, что IP = 200.200.200.200), который находится в России, а так же сервер в Нидерландах (IP = 100.100.100.100). Пинг между серверами порядка 40 мс.
Задача в том, чтобы с сервера в Нидерландах подключаться и работать с БД максимально быстро.
Если подключиться к БД с 100.100.100.100 вот таким образом:

```
mysql -uroot -p -h 200.200.200.200
```

Только из-за задержек в сети даже простые запросы исполняются со скорость 80 мс (40 мс на запрос и столько же на ответ). Это непозволительно много. Появилась идея настроить домен на популярной CDN cloudflare и подключаться к бд через эти сервера. Суть в том, что cloudflare использует множество серверов доставки контента, что позволяет снизить пинг между серверами до пары-тройки мс. В итоге подключаемся вот так:

```
mysql -uroot -p -h domain.ru
```

Если на cf отлючить проксирование (то есть DNS сервер будет возвращать родной адрес ру сервера 200.200.200.200 по домену domain.ru), то всё здорово работает, однако пинг тот же самый 40 мс, а если включить проксирование, то подключение к MySQL не работает вообще (бесконечное подключение). По видимому cf блокирует подобные запросы к динамическому контенту.

По очевидным причинам объединение серверов в кластер не имеет смысла (т.к сеть никуда не пропадает, а сами сервера находятся в разных дц)

На сервере MySQL добавлен пользователь с правами на удалённое подключение и сам сервер настроен на работу из сети.

Может быть нужна дополнительная настройка cf для этой задачи? Или есть смысл использовать другие CDN?

Comment: Вы явно не понимаете, что такое CDN и как это работает. Во-первых, MySQL — это не «контент». Во-вторых, CDN занимаются тем, что **кэшируют ответы HTTP-сервера**, и работать с MySQL (и любыми другими протоколами помимо HTTP) они в принципе не умеют и не должны уметь

Comment: Ну и для «динамического контента» использование CDN не имеет смысла: если CDN его не будет кэшировать (потому что он динамический), то он будет перенаправлять все запросы на основной сервер, и тогда задержки CDN и задержки сервера просуммируются и всё станет совсем долго